# deploying WT web app on google cloud

Tags: web, google-compute-engine, wt

I have build a wt (witty) hello world example and I am trying to deploy this on a Google Cloud instance. It seems to run fine locally (hence it has all the necessary library dependencies). However, I am not able to it to deploy on the server.

I am trying (using my actual http address which is different from the example below)

```
./hello --docroot . --http-address 105.150.47.754 --http-port 80
```

but it responds with

```
Error (asio): bind : cannot assign requested address
```

It seems to work fine using (0.0.0.0/0)

The cloud instance allows HTTP tcp/80 traffic.

I have tried

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' ~/hello
```

to allow non-root users to publish on ports below 1024, but also to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to listen on the specified IP address, one of the following is likely true:

1) Something (such as a web server) is already listening at that address on port 80, or

2) The IP address you are using is not assigned to one of the machine's network interfaces.

Using (0.0.0.0/0) with port 80 tells the Wt web server (wthttpd) to listen on all available local interfaces. Therefore, using that address will work with any available network interface assigned any IP address with port 80 available.

Comment: the /hello --docroot . --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 80 solution works, but seems insecure. Any thoughts on the risks?

Comment: Actually ./hello --docroot . --http-address 10.150.0.4 --http-port 80 also works where 10.150.0.4 is the internal IP. This seems more secure, but not sure it this is production quality.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about about the web server listening on all network interfaces.  Putting the web server on the internet is going to make it accessible to everyone, anyway. I think it's more important, however, to use https rather than http.  Using https is really easy these days, especially since you can use a Let's Encrypt cert, which costs nothing but the setup time.  The newer versions of wthttpd connected to your Wt app and using openssl pass all the security checks.   Also use a firewall to block ports you don't need to make publicly accessible.

Comment: Limiting the Wt app to listening only on one interface would be useful if you have multiple interfaces and only want to use one of them for your webapp.  For security purposes, I'm not sure you gain much by limiting the listening interface, unless you have some kind of  specific infrastructure set up that has one interface that is somehow more secure than other interfaces.  Also, if you ever change the IP address, you'll have to remember to change the http-address parameter to match it.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification!